# UICollectionview updating random images in the wrong place

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, uicollectionview

I am new to parsing json in Swift and in my app I created an inbox. In this inbox, I load a profile image and a name in every cell. I found an API online with video game characters and their images for a test. However, when the json is parsed and put in the cell, the app loads the cells and occasionally the images move around to other cells or duplicate. I have seen this posted before, but none of the past answers have solved my solution.

Here is what it looked like when it loaded which is incorrect

[image: Here is what it looked like when it loaded which is incorrect]

Here is what happened one second later which is still incorrect and you can see duplication

[image: Here is what happened one second later which is still incorrect and you can see duplication]

This is my CollectionViewCell.Swift File

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imageCell: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var dateCell: UILabel!

override func prepareForReuse() {
    self.imageCell.image = nil
    self.imageCell.setNeedsDisplay() // tried adding after some     recommendations
    self.setNeedsDisplay()         // tried adding after some recommendations
    super.prepareForReuse()

    }

}
```

This is my main inbox view controller extension for the image I found online

```
extension UIImageView {
func downloadedFrom(url: URL, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
    contentMode = mode
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard
            let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,     httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
            let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
            let data = data, error == nil,
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            self.image = image
        }
        }.resume()
}
func downloadedFrom(link: String, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
    guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
    downloadedFrom(url: url, contentMode: mode)

    }
}
```

This is the rest of the inbox view controller code (deleted unrelated code from it for the purpose of this question)

```
class InboxViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var inboxCollection: UICollectionView!


struct Hero: Decodable {
    let localized_name: String
    let img: String
}

var heroes = [Hero]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    inboxCollection.dataSource = self

    let url = URL(string: "https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

        if error == nil {

            do {
                self.heroes = try JSONDecoder().decode([Hero].self, from: data!)
            }catch {
                print("Parse Error")
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.inboxCollection.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }.resume()



}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.heroes.count
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.dateCell.text = heroes[indexPath.row].localized_name.capitalized
    let defaultLink = "https://api.opendota.com"
    cell.imageCell.image = nil
    let completelink = defaultLink + heroes[indexPath.row].img
    cell.imageCell.image = nil
    cell.imageCell.downloadedFrom(link: completelink)
    cell.imageCell.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.imageCell.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageCell.frame.height / 2
    cell.imageCell.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    cell.imageCell.image = nil

    return cell

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be setting UIImageView's image within the UIImageView. In fact, don't even create two separate methods - you have no good reason to. Download each image in your UIViewController and use a dictionary to map a hero's name to their image like so:

```
var heroImages = [String:URL]()
    func getDataFromUrl(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> ()) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            completion(data, response, error)
        }.resume()
    }

func getImages() {
    for hero in self.heroes {
        let url = NSURL(string: hero)
        getDataFromURL(url: url, completion: {(data: Data?, response:URLResponse?, error: Error?) in 
        if (data != nil) { 
            image = UIImage(data: data)
            heroImages[hero] = image }
            if (heroImages.count == self.heroes.count) {
                 // We've downloaded all the images, update collection view
                 DispatchQueue.main.async { self.collectionView.reloadData() }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, that seems like a great idea. Do you mind copying and pasting my original code (Everything I included) and putting this in there so I can see how to actually implement this and what it would like like when loading this images in the actually collection view functions. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I tried implementing this code, but I am getting a lot of errors with your getImages function at the beginning

Comment: @LeviK: Apologies for the code errors, but I've updated the code. hopefully it will work. Anyway, this code goes in your UIViewController subclass.

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'InboxViewController.Hero' to expected argument type 'String' & Use of unresolved identifier 'getDataFromURL' & Expected ')' in expression list still (any idea how to resolve these?)